# how to sideload taskpane in Excel using VBA macro in macOS

Tags: excel, vba, office-js

I have a task pane project which is working properly when I am adding it from **insert-> My Addins-> Show task pane** but I want to perform all this task using Macro/sub.

I want a macro which side loads my custom task pane in excel.

I have manifest.xml in the document folder. my Excel version is v16.36.

Comment: It feels very weird to me that you would want to load an Office add-in with VBA.... kinda like using 90's technology when 2020 technology is available.

Comment: @BigBen haha yes. I got some weird requirement this time. Let me know if you can help me with the answer :) .

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no supported interaction between VBA/VSTO/COM and Office.js. They are very different technologies with entirely different architectures.

Web add-ins are a multiplatform concept meaning all APIs exposed in JavaScript most function across all platforms (namely Windows, Online, Mac, iOS), they are sandboxed and cannot communicate with the OS or installed programs (at least without helper or broker applications/libraries).

However, VBA macros are old technology, which is not a multiplatform supported, they are not exposed in our office js API.

Comment: I think we can accomplish it this with the VBA but I am not aware of the process. Because from Excel-> Insert -> My Add-ins it is working fine which is also VBA.

Comment: What do you mean Excel -> Insert -> My Add-ins is VBA? How is that VBA?

Comment: @Ethan, I ment, In Excel we have Insert tab.. When you click on Insert tab, you will find "My Add-ins" dropdown button. Where I am able to see my Web Addin. and It is working fine. Now I want to accomplish the same task using Macro.

Answer (score 1):

The integration between VBA and office.js is not possible. You have to use **Yeoman Generator** to create office addin.

link- [Yeoman Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator)